# How is Jmockit different from EasyMock? Which is better to use?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock, jmockit

I have for long worked on EasyMocking in JUnits. I am pretty much comfortable with this but now I want to know how EasyMocks are different from Jmockits. I tried going through their documentation and I found out that the syntax is a bit different. But yet I could not figure out if there is any difference in their performances. 
Can anyone help me figure out what are the points that make either of them better than the other? Is there any special element in JMockit that is not found in the other?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many differences between JMockit and EasyMock/jMock/Mockito/PowerMock.
These are the major ones:

1. Support for integration testing: JMockit supports an [*out-of-container* integration testing approach](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/EnterpriseApplications.html), similar to what the [Spring Test module](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html) provides, but also supporting Java EE. The other mocking libraries only support isolated unit testing with mock objects.
2. A ["faking"](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html) API (see also in [xUnit Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fake%20Object.html)), in addition to the [mocking](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html) API. Each one of the other mocking libraries only have a mocking API.
3. Full support for "mocking", in addition to "mock *objects*". Other mocking libraries work with mock objects which they create and which need to be passed in somehow to the code under test. With EasyMock/jMock/Mockito, `static` methods, constructors, and "`new`-ed" objects cannot be mocked at all. PowerMock supports full mocking as well, but still focused on mock objects (specifically, new-ed objects must be "replaced" with mock objects through `whenNew` recording, while with JMockit a test can simply declare a `@Mocked` field).
4. Support for mocking/faking of `final` classes and methods. Only PowerMock also provides this support. Mockito recently added an "inline mock maker" which adds support for `final`s, but it's not active by default and may not be as reliable.
5. Support for mocking/faking of unspecificied subclasses and interface implementations (where the test only declares a base type to be mocked/faked).
6. In the mocking API, expectations on methods with multiple parameters can be recorded/verified with argument matchers (such as `anyString`, etc.) only for *some* parameters, while other mocking APIs require such matchers for *every* single parameter.
7. Also in the mocking API, expectations can be explicitly *verified* after the tested code was exercised, just like in Mockito. EasyMock/jMock do not support this verification model.

As for performance, mocking a type with JMockit (done through *class redefinition*) probably has a higher runtime overhead when compared to creating a mock object with EasyMock/jMock/Mockito (done through *subclass definition*), and lower when compared with PowerMock (done through *class definition* on a custom classloader). However, you should only notice the difference in performance if there is a lot of mocking being done, which most likely indicates overuse of mocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a blog post about the differences between them (and also mockito!) here: http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-vs-easymock-vs-jmockit

While they all have different syntax and different ways of working, you should be able to achieve whatever you need in regards to mocking with either framework.

Comment: Through the documents, several advantages over easyMocks are found.
Its true and evident that jmockit has introduced a structure while writing testcases and the partial mocking is more logical here. Similarly argument matching also declare jmockit a winner. But yet all of this does not say that someone must start using jmockit instead of easymocks.
Is there any big difference in the usage of both the frameworks?
Like is there any functionality that easymock cant do but the other can?